# Referencing Documents between 2 MongoDB Collections

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb, one-to-many

I'm building an app where employees can be added to the database and each employee belongs to a particular company, which can be chosen from a select field on the form. The form to add employees also contains a salary field and I would like to be able to display the companies with their total salary expense (based on the sum of salaries of its employees).

At first, I imagined I would use a single "employees" collection. Then, for example, choose "Apple" as the company, and finally, in the end, I would end up with a list of employee objects where I can loop through all the employees where "Apple" was the company and sum all the salary fields. This ended up being a poor approach. Next, I decided to create a separate collection of "companies". Then, before saving an employee, I look up the company object ID, and save that as the company.

For instance,

```
{ firstName: "Bob", lastName, "Smith", company: "5b62a456e7179a07334478a5", salary: 7}
```

Where `"5b62a456e7179a07334478a5"` is the "_id" field of Apple. 
How do I continue to define this relationship in MongoDB?

Do I add an employees field to each company and try to save each employee to a company upon saving them to the employee's collection? In this way, I can try to access the sum of all employees within each company to obtain a total salary expense.

But I would then have to write to two different collections each time a new employee is saved. Also, what would the flow of that even look like? I would need to use the company _id field to look up the company and then save the employee to the company. So, would I have to perform a query and two writes on each new employee save?

Comment: Keep the collections the way you have. Use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to join the company collection with employee collection on company id. To get salaries you can do `db.companies.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "employees",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "company",
        as: "employees"
    },
    {   
        $addFields:{
           "totalSalary":{$sum:"$employees.salary"}
        } 
    }
}])`

Comment: Thank you for the link, I'm reading the docs now on the agg framework and $lookup. So, upon creating an employee document, I should use the `"_id"` field of the company to look up the company and save the employee's `_id` to the company as `employees: []`

Comment: Yw. No need to save employees inside company that is what you get when you use $lookup. For the saving part you just need to make sure when you save employee you add the company id. For query part you can use the $lookup inside aggregation to get the sum of salaries.

Comment: I keep getting `SyntaxError: invalid property id` when I try to use $lookup, I'm trying to query the companies with the syntax specified

Comment: Sorry, syntax errors.  Try  `db.companies.aggregate([{"$lookup":{"from":"employees","localField":"_id","foreignField":"company","as":"employees"}},{"$addFields":{"totalSalary":{"$sum":"$employees.salary"}}}])`

Comment: I noticed that when i save the _id it looks like this `"ObjectId(\"5b62a497e7179a07334478ce\")"` - the browser is escaping the quotes - in my angular code i save it like this `return 'ObjectId("5b62a497e7179a07334478ce")';` - so i think that might be affecting it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177373/discussion-between-frederick-john-and-veeram).

Comment: @Veeram can you join chat for one min

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lookup feature to do a "join"

```
db.table1.aggregate([{
    $lookup: {
        from: "table2",
        localField: "table2column",
        foreignField: "table1key",
        as: "alias"
    },
    {   
        $project:{
           //columns you want
        } 
    }
}])
```

That being said...if your data is relational and not obscenely huge, a relational database might be a better choice.